# How to don't trigger right mouse click on Ctrl+LeftMouseClick in Firefox on MacOS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, keyboard-shortcuts, mouseclick-event

I want to use a shortcut with Ctrl+LeftMouseClick in a React project.

It works fine on my Mac with Chrome but in Firefox the shortcut triggers the right mouse click (event.button = 2). I think this is because of the MacOS Right Click function with Ctrl+LeftMouse Click.

But why does it work in Chrome and how could I get it to work in Firefox, too?

Comment: Ctrl+left click is used in most browsers to open a link in a new tab. Are you sure you want to break your users' expectations like that?

Comment: @Thomas Yes I am sure, the shortcut is only used in a 3D canvas scene without links :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following Firefox console test results in plain Javascript will help you devise an appropriate React test.  I observe that I can capture the ctrl-click on the trackpad in Firefox with the following listener.  I notice that `evt.button` is always 2 for me.  However if I am using a trackpad, then I can distinguish between a two-finger-press triggered right-click by looking at `evt.buttons`.  I did not test with a mouse but I would expect that a mouse may need to be treated differently.  Also, beware that I have read that the ctrl-click masquerading as right-click might be a user controlled option.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', (evt) => {
    if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.buttons == 1) {
        console.log("ctrl-click detected");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```